# How to find the maximum value of a difference between these values in an arithmetic series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> The following is an arithmetic progression and $m$ is a positive integer.
>
> $$m, \underbrace{\dots}_{n+1 \text{ terms}}, 33, \underbrace{\dots}_{3n+1 \text{ terms}}, 113$$
>
> Find the maximum value of $n-m$.

Does it require the use of derivatives? I understand that in an arithmetic progression this equation is used:

$$a_{n}=a_{1}+(n-1)d$$

but I don't know how to relate it with the problem or if it would be used at all.

Edit:

Looking at the solution from the source where I found this problem the author addresses it this way:

Because $m>0m$ , $m\in \mathbb{N}$ (sidenote: not sure how to conclude this)

Therefore,

$$m;\underset{\overbrace{\textrm{n+1 terms}}}{\cdots};33;\underset{\overbrace{\textrm{3n+1 terms}}}{\cdots};113$$

33 is positioned in the place labeled as $\textrm{n+3}$, which comes from $\textrm{1+n+1+1}$,

from $a_{n}=a_{1}+(n-1)d$

$a_{n+3}=m+d(n+2)=33$,

then,

$$33;\underset{\overbrace{\textrm{3n+1 terms}}}{\cdots};113$$

$$a_{3n+3}=33+(3n+2)d=113$$

Which leads to:

$$(3n+2)d=80$$

The part which gets tricky comes here as the author concludes that $n=106$, $d=\frac{1}{4}$ (without explaining how).

Replacing $n=106$, $d=\frac{1}{4}$

$$a_{106+3}=m+\frac{1}{4}(106+2)=33$$

$$m=33-\frac{1}{4}(106+2)=6$$

Then the author concludes in order $n-m$ to be maximum $n$ should be maximum and $m$ minimum.

Therefore, $n-m=106-6=100$,

which is the answer provided. Although the above approach does not require calculus topics (i.e derivatives). Instead guesses values based on a lineal equation with two unknowns. This part is something which is confusing. Any help on an alternative that can lead to that answer but with a more logical and easy to follow algorithm?.

Answer (score 1):

$$m+(n+2)d=33\tag1$$
$$m+(4n+4)d=113\tag2$$

Hence we get, from $(1) - (2)$, 
$$(3n+2)d=80 \Rightarrow n=\frac{80}{3d}-\frac{2}{3}$$
And $4\times (1) - (2)$ gives,
$$3m+4d=19 \Rightarrow m=\frac{19}{3}-\frac{4d}{3}$$

So, we get
$$n-m=\frac{80}{3d}-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{19}{3}+\frac{4d}{3}=\frac{4d^2+80}{3d}-7$$

To make $n-m$ maximum, differentiate $\frac{4d^2+80}{3d}$ with respect to $d$ and equate to $0$. Also check the second derivative at that point to ensure it is a maximum.

Now, conclude accordingly.

Hope you can finish this.

Comment: By continuing from where you left off should be like this, ${\left ( \frac{4d^{2}}{3d}+\frac{80}{3d} \right )}'={\left ( \frac{4d}{3}+\frac{80}{3d} \right )}'=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{80}{3}d^{-2}=0, d=2\sqrt{5}$, and the second derivative will become ${\left ( \frac{4}{3}-\frac{80}{3}d^{-2} \right )}'=0, \frac{-160}{3}d^{-3}=0, d^{-3}=0.$ But it is the latter part which does not make sense. Moreover it cannot be guaranteed to be maximum. Mind if you solve this part?. Now, why 33 is $a_{n+1}$, this part is not very clear to me.

Comment: And you dont equate the second derivative to 0. Please read some standard text on this and try it. Else you wont learn anything.

Comment: But if its $a_{n+2}$ wouldn't it be $a_{n+2}=m+((n+2)-1)d=33$, hence $a_{n+2}=m+(n+1)d=33$?.

Comment: I was wrong, it should be $a_{n+3}$, since $m$ is first term, followed by $n+1$ terms.

Comment: Regarding the second derivative I made a mistake. It should had been $\frac{160}{3}d^{-3}$ since there are two roots in the first derivative $d= -2\sqrt{5}$ would be a local maximum by entering this into $\frac{160}{3}(-2\sqrt{5})^{-3}$. But a problem arises, ${\left ( \frac{4d^{2}+80}{3d} -7\right )}={\left ( \frac{4(-2\sqrt{5})^{2}+80}{3(-2\sqrt{5})} -7\right )}={\left ( \frac{160}{-6\sqrt{5})} -7\right )}={\left ( \frac{-16\sqrt{5}}{3} -7\right )}=\frac{-16\sqrt{5}-21}{3}$ and this part does not seem correct.

Comment: Exactly, you have reached the answer. Check that $d$ must be positive, since the terms are increasing (since $a_{n+3}=33$ and $a_{4n+5}=113$). So $d<0$ is not possible. And for $d>o$, there is no local maxima, rather there is a global minima. Hence the answer is $n-m$ has no upper bound, it can be $\infty$. Is the logic clear?

Comment: The result of $-2\sqrt{5}$ makes the equation to become negative since there is no other negative in the denominator to cancel it. Regarding the global minima, would be the other result (the positive one), which would make it be $\frac{16\sqrt{5}-21}{3}$, although I got the idea about not having an upper bound the problem is neither one of the roots evaluated in the equation check with the right answer. There is logic but I feel something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $d$ be the common difference of successive members, we have
$$m+(n+2)d=33\tag1$$
$$m+(4n+4)d=113\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$, we have
$$3m=19-4d,\quad 3n+2=\frac{80}{d}$$

Now, since $m$ is a positive integer, we see that $4d$ has to be an integer less than $19$, from which we can write $d=\frac{N}{4}$ where $N\lt 19$ is an integer.

Also, since $n$ is a non-negative integer, we see that $\frac{80}{d}=\frac{320}{N}$ is a positive integer.

It follows from this that $N\lt 19$ has to be a positive divisor of $320$.

So, $N$ has to be either $1,2,4,5,8,10,16$.

Here, using $d=\frac N4$, we have
$$n-m=\frac 13\left(\frac{80}{d}-2\right)-\frac{19-4d}{3}=\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7$$

Now, we define $$f(N)=\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7$$
to have
$$f(N)-f(N+1)=\frac{-N^2-N+320}{3N(N+1)}$$

Here, note that when $f(N)-f(N+1)\gt 0$, i.e. $f(N)\gt f(N+1)$, $f(N)$ is decreasing.

So, we see that $f(N)$ is decreasing when $-N^2-N+320\gt 0\implies (0\lt)\ N\lt \frac{-1+\sqrt{1281}}{2}$ where
$$17=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1225}}{2}\lt \frac{-1+\sqrt{1281}}{2}\lt\frac{-1+\sqrt{1369}}{2}=18$$

Since we already see that $N$ has to be either $1,2,4,5,8,10,16$ (note that all of these values are smaller than $17$), the maximum of $n-m$ is attained when $N$ is the minimum, i.e. $N=1$.

Therefore, the maximum of $n-m$ is $f(1)=100$ when $N=1,d=\frac 14,m=6,n=106$.

Comment: Where do $f(N)-f(N+1)$ come from?. I'm also stuck at trying to know how did you get with $\sqrt{1225}$ and $\sqrt{1369}$?, the other seems to be logical as it comes from the value of the discriminant from $-N^{2}-N+320$. How exactly do I know $f(N)$ is decreasing?. What's the purpose of $17<\frac{-1+\sqrt{1281}}{2}<18$? $N=1$ is not very clear to me, mind if you explain a bit how do I get to that number?. I think that's the key as a domino effect the rest is easy for values of d, m and n. But the N in the function I dont get it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: (1) I defined $f(N)$ as $(n-m=)\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7$. Then, I just calculated $f(N)-f(N+1)$. (2) $\sqrt{1225},\sqrt{1369}$ come from the fact that  $1225=35^2,1369=37^2$. (3) Note that $f(N)-f(N+1)\gt 0$ is equivalent to $f(N+1)\lt f(N)$ which means $f(N)$ is decreasing. (4) Please note that $N$ has to be either $1,2,4,5,8,10,16$. (note that all these values are less than $17$) Since we see that in $0\lt N\lt 17+\alpha$, $f(N)$ is decreasing, $f(1)$ is the maximum. (4) Please note that $N=4d$. The reason I use $N$ is that $N$ is an integer (while $d$ is not).

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: I added some explanations.

Comment: Okay, but my question was why did you decided to use $f(N+1)$?. Why not let's say $f(N)-f(N+2)$? Is it because $+1$ is the minimum difference between positive integers? I am still unable to understand where do $\frac{-1+\sqrt{1225}}{2}$ comes?. If its because $35^{2}$, where does that $35$ come from?, the same applies for $37$. $f(N)$ is decreasing because of this symbol $>$? I can understand the symbolic expressions in your argumentation but it would help a lot if you could explain it with words.

Comment: The part where you say that $N$ has to be less than $17$ because $N$ is between $0$ and $17+\alpha$ comes from $17<\frac{-1+\sqrt{1281}}{2}<18$? There is another answer which does uses derivatives, however it does not come to the same result, why such approach fails?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: (1) "$+1$ is the minimum difference between positive integers" Yes, you are right. (2) $35^2$ and $37^2$ are nearest odd square number to $1281$. In order for $\frac{-1+\sqrt{\text{(something)}}}{2}$ to be an integer, $(\text{something})$ has to be an odd square number. (3) Yes, the symbol $\gt$ is the key. That $f(N)\gt f(N+1)$ holds for $N=1,2,\cdots, 17$ means that we have $f(1)\gt f(2)\gt \cdots \gt f(17)\gt f(18)$ (easier to understand?). (4) Using derivatives is not needed. The key is to use the fact that $m,n$ are integers. It seems another answer doesn't use it.

Comment: It took me a while to get the idea but your last sentence about $f(1)>f(2)>...>f(18)$ made it clear. However does the argument involving the maximum value of $n-m$ (attained when $N=1$) can be extended to all situations within arithmetic sequences involving integers in the positive interval? I'm also wondering whether if it was necessary to continue with a quadratic equation as somebody could have stopped at $f(N)=\frac{N}{3}+\frac{320}{3N}-7$ and from then start inserting values $N=1,2,3...$ since $f(N)$ is decreasing then it could be concluded that $N$ is maximum at $1$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: (1) I don't know exactly what you meant by "all situations", but if you understand the key of the argument of the answer, it would work in "many" situations. (2) Of course, you can insert values (we have only $7$ values $N=1,2,4,5,8,10,16$ in our situation). But I gave you much more useful explanation which can be used in the situation where we have a lot of values to be inserted. In our situation, solving the quadratic inequality helps a lot since that tells us that $f(1)\gt f(2)\gt \cdots\gt f(18)$ without inserting any values (without too much calculations).

Comment: What I mean by the question was if steps (algorithm) you have used can be extended to similar cases in arithmetic sequences? In a comment above there was an error in parenthesis but what you meant was $f(N)=n-m$ otherwise if $f(N)=f(n-m)$, then it would not make sense as $n-m$ would become $1$. Although you say that derivatives is not necessary, don't they come to the rescue when situations such as maxima and minima arises?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: (1) Yes, I think it can be extended. (2) $n-m=\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7=f(N)$, not $f(N)=f(n-m)$. (3) Yes, derivatives are very very useful, but *in our situation*, derivatives are not necessary since we can solve in a much more elementary way as my answer shows.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: I now see that what you called "an error in parenthesis". There was no error in "I defined $f(N)$ as $(n-m=)\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7$". What I meant was that the part $n-m=$ is not so important here since $f(N)$ is a function of $N$. Anyway, sorry for the confusion. It just meant "I defined $f(N)$ as $n-m=\frac N3+\frac{320}{3N}-7$".

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb of when to use derivatives and when not to?. I'm still at the beginner level on these topics and it seems logical to being attracted like a magnet when maxima and minima appears.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Oh, a good question. First of all, in this question we are facing, we don't need to use derivatives because the function $f(N)$ is "simple" (hard to define, though) and $N$ is an integer. So, considering the sign of $f(N+1)-f(N)$ (which is also simple) is enough to know when it's decreasing. But, if the function we face is not "simple" and we have to consider the function over real numbers, then derivatives help. In short, when we have to consider a quesiton over real numbers, derivatives help, but if over integers, then, often, derivatives are not necessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just to propose an alternative simple and easy to follow approach (as requested in the OP) that maybe could have been that of who conceived the original problem and did not explain the final step. Starting from $(3n+2)d=80 \,\,\,\,\,$, we have $n=80/(3d) - 2/3\,\,\,\,$. Substituting this in $(n+2)d=33-m\,\,\,\,\,$, we directly get

$$m=\frac{19-4d}{3}$$

Now since $m$ is a positive integer and $d$ must be positive, the only possible values of $d$ are $1/4\,$, $1\,$, and $4\,$. These values lead to $m=6\,$, $m=5\,$, and $m=1\,$, respectively. The corresponding values of $n$ are  $n=106\,$, $n=26\,$, and $n=6\,$, respectively. So the solution that maximizes $n-m\,\,$ is the first one, with $n=106\,\,$ and $d=1/4\,\,$.

Comment: That's a good observation, and it uses trial and error approach to solve the problem. Since there are few values you can come up to the answer quickly.

Comment: This is IMHO the right way to do this problem. @Chris Don't shun "trial and error"! When elementary number theory leaves you with only finitely many possibilities it is a perfectly valid approach to try them all, and see which works! Calculus is quite the wrong tool for this problem. And for my money also one of the duller parts in math, but your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your feedback. It has been a while since this question was posted but to me I felt that the most obvious choice was to use calculus as it said "maximum" yet in the end seems that just trying out the few values can render an answer. But at the time I faced this problem it felt that I may end by trying many values and not getting an answer at all. In other words not getting scared when having to deal with these things.